# Can I profile an iOS 7 device with Xcode 4.6.3?

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcode4.6, xcode4.6.3

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 7 installed. I need to use Xcode 4.6.3 for building with the iOS 6 SDK. When I try profiling the app just hangs in the launch screen. Is it possible to profile an iOS 7 device with Xcode 4.6.3?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem, but this problem was solved as I updated to Xcode 5 So I think you need Xcode 5.
EDIT: and to traget iOS6 you can set the deployment to iOS6 in project configuration

Comment: Deployment Target is not the same as Base SDK. When building with Xcode 5 f.ex. I can't build with any other Base SDK than 7.